# How to present tokens from stringtokenizer in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl

Kind Note: I've tried my best to present this question as clear as possible. In case, if you want more details or if the question is not clear kindly let me know rather downvoting the question, I'll edit for you.

I've a `list` of `strings` in this format `CatalogSwitcherInterrupter-active__..false` and I want to present this on jsp in the attached screenshot.

[image]

Below is the html snippet for the above html table.

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
   <th>Component</th>
   <th>Properties</th>
   <th>J01</th>
   <th>J02</th>
   <th>W01</th>
   <th>W02</th>

  </tr>
 </table>
```

Component td data will be replaced by **CatalogSwitcherInterrupter**, Properties td data will be replaced by **active** and **J01 ,J02,W01,W02** td data will be replaced by true or false based on the string. I'll use `jstl` tags to render this data dynamically.

Have used `StringTokenizer` with `-__..` as a delimiter, it didn't give the desired result and making code more dirty by increasing the code inside scriplet tags.

Now, I would like to request smart people here, Is there a better way to split this string `CatalogSwitcherInterrupter-active__..false` using `StringTokenizer` or `split` method and present on jsp using jstl tags or minimal scriplets?

I'm relatively a beginner in java web programming. Any kind of inputs is of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an MVC framework? Even if you aren't, the MVC approach is better for such tasks. I'd do the following:

1. Create a POJO with all the display fields.
2. Instead of producing a list of strings on the backend produce a list of classes created in #1. This would be the controller part of MVC. Pass the created list to the view as an attribute.
3. In your jsp output all data received from the backend in a simple foreach loop. You can access all the attributes of a POJO that have a getter method in JSTL.